# Ordenar en Mongoose artículos por nombre, y sus imágenes por "posición"

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

Estoy haciendo una aplicación con react, graphql, apollo y mongoose, and I me gustaría ordenar un alista de artículos por nombre (en este caso no hay problema alguno), y a su vez, dentro de la lista de imagenes que tiene cada artículo, ordenar éstas según el valor de "posición". Este sería un ejemplo de mis datos en pseudo-json:

```
{data: 
  {
  name: "Name 3"
  Images:[
    {
      name: "Image 3.22"
      position: 2
    },
    {
      name: "Image 3.91"
      position: 1
    },
    {
      name: "Image 3.73"
    }
  },{
{
  name: "Name 2"
  Images:[
    {
      name: "Image 2.53"
      position: 3
    },
    {
      name: "Image 2.61"
      position: 1
    },
    {
      name: "Image 2.32"
      position: 2
    }
  }
```

El resultado debería ser:

```
{data:
  {
  name: "Name 2",
  Images:[
    {
      name: "Image 2.61"
      position: 1
    },
    {
      name: "Image 2.32"
      position: 2
    },
    {
      name: "Image 2.53"
      position: 3
    }]
  },{
  name: "Name 3"
  Images:[
    {
      name: "Image 3.91"
      position: 1
    },
    {
      name: "Image 3.22"
      position: 2
    },
    {
      name: "Image 3.73"
    }]
  }
}
```

Para ordenar hago `sort({name: "asc", "Images.position": "desc"})` pero sale mal (ordena por nombre pero la lista de imagenes ni de coña). En el caso de que la posición sea nula, debería ir al final de la lista (ya rizando el rizo xD)
Alguna idea??

Answer (score 0):

No se si encontraste la respuesta pero te respondo por si acaso.

Según indicas en tu consulta, el error que encuentro es en cómo realizas el método **`"sort"`**, indicas **`"desc"`** o **`"asc"`** cuando en `MongoDB` no trabaja con esa sintaxis.

Te indico:

> Modo Ascendente:
>
> ```
> db.getCollection('collection1').find({}).sort({name:1})
> ```
>
> Modo Descendente:
>
> ```
> db.getCollection('collection1').find({}).sort({name:-1})
> ```

La solución a tu problema seria:

> `db.getCollection('collection1').find({}).sort({name:1,'Images.position':-1})`

Espero haberte ayudado.

Saludos